# Wikidata Sparql: how to get a list of actors that where never directed by a given person?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Let's say I want a list of actors that were never directed by Tim Burton among a list of popular movies.

I tried to do it with this steps:

- Select all actors that Tim Burton ever directed (sub select)
- Select a list of actors from a list of popular movies (by imdb ids)
- Exclude all actors from the first selection in the second selection (`NOT IN`)

Here is a code I tried that do not works (the `NOT IN` fail, I don't know why):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?actor ?actorLabel
WHERE {
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424
        ;wdt:P161 ?actor
        ;wdt:P345 ?imdbId .
  {
    SELECT ?excludeActors
    WHERE {
      ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424
            ; wdt:P57 wd:Q56008
            ; wdt:P161 ?excludeActors .
    }
  } .
  FILTER(?actor NOT IN (?excludeActors)) . 
  FILTER(?imdbId = "tt1077368" || ?imdbId = "tt0167260") . 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr" }
}
```

Or follow [this link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Factor%20%3FactorLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Bwdt%3AP161%20%3Factor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Bwdt%3AP345%20%3FimdbId%20.%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3FexcludeActors%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%20wdt%3AP57%20wd%3AQ56008%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3B%20wdt%3AP161%20%3FexcludeActors%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20.%0A%20%20FILTER(%3Factor%20NOT%20IN%20(%3FexcludeActors))%20.%20%0A%20%20FILTER(%3FimdbId%20%3D%20%22tt1077368%22%20%7C%7C%20%3FimdbId%20%3D%20%22tt0167260%22)%20.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20(%3Factor%20%3D%20wd%3AQ180338)%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22fr%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%20100)

(there is a filter on Christopher Lee that you can remove [last one], it is used to highlight what I explain here:)

In this code I have two movies: Dark Shadows (directed by Tim Burton) and The Lord of the Rings 3. In this example Christopher Lee is present in both movies, which means he should be excluded since Tim Burton directed him in Dark Shadows.
You can see that he his in the list.

I really don't understand why the `NOT IN` fail with the sub select. I tried the sub Select request and I found Christopher Lee inside which means he should be excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want all actors that acted in the given movies, but have never acted in any movie directed by Tim Burton. I would use `FILTER NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?actor ?actorLabel
WHERE {
  VALUES ?imdbId { "tt1077368" "tt0167260" }
  ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424
        ;wdt:P161 ?actor
        ;wdt:P345 ?imdbId .
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      [] wdt:P31 wd:Q11424
            ; wdt:P57 wd:Q56008
            ; wdt:P161 ?actor .
  } 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr" }
}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: You understood perfectly and gave me the correct answer, thank you !

Comment: This looks like it could work, but I'd suggest `values ?imbdId { "tt1077368" "tt0167260" }` rather than the first filter.

Comment: Thanks Joshua ! This trick will allow me to win some space for my requests ! (I have a lot of imdb ids and the HTTP Get request are size limited.)
Do one of you also know how to avoid aving results without a label ? Sometimes (not in this case) I have results where ?varLabel would equal the id (Q11...11). I added a filter that works and which is rdfs:label ?id_label filter (lang(?id_label) ="fr") but maybe there is another way ?

I also need to know how to look for a text case insensitive like:
?label rdfs:label "christopher lee"@en (it doesn't work)

Comment: I edited the answer to use values instead of the filter. As for the labels, I can't think of another way. For case-insensitive text comparison, you can bind the label to a variable, use [LCASE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-lcase) to make it lowercase, and compare in a filter. That kind of query can get very slow, however.

Comment: Yes I found the LCASE which only works on filters but I always have query expiration with this technique.